# Why is try_emplace not implemented for std::multimap?

Tags: c++, c++17

C++17 introduces the `try_emplace` method for `std::map`, so now I can write code like below:

```
struct Test
{
    Test(int i, int j){}
};
std::map<int, Test> tmap;
tmap.try_emplace(10, 10, 10);
```

But there is no `try_emplace` for `std::multimap<int, Test>`, so `piecewise_construct` is still needed.

Is there a technical reason for this?

Comment: `std::multimap` does not need `try_emplace` as it always inserts, so `emplace` is enough.

Comment: I see, but it's really handy if piecewise_construct can be get rid of for `std::multimap`

Answer (score 14):

> is there a technical reason for this?

Yes. The purpose of `try_emplace()` is to not do anything if the key already exists in the map. But for `std::{unordered_,}multi{map,set}`, you can have multiple values for each key. That is, indeed, the point of these containers: to have multiple values for a given key.

As a result, `try_emplace()` cannot fail for these containers - so it would be confusing and pointless to provide such a function.

---

Based on the comments, it seems that the motivation is just the part of `try_emplace()` that makes it easier to emplace a value. You can write a helper function for that:

```
template <typename Map, typename Key, typename... Args>
auto emplace_value(Map& map, Key&& key, Args&&... args) {
    return map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                       std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Key>(key)),
                       std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Which would let you write `emplace_value(tmap, 10, 10, 10)`, even for `{unordered_,}multimap`.

Comment: Well, one _might_ still want to insert some elements only in case the key isn't present already, even in a multimap. Just it's probably not common enough to warrant having that method in the standard library.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yeah, they can still do that, but as it's a sign that you may be using the wrong container, the standard prefers not to give us a feature to do it. Just like how you can't arbitrarily arithmetise non-random-access iterators -- if you really feel the need then there's `std::next` but the standard won't make it trivial for you because it doesn't think you should be doing it usually.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit not sure that's a good analogy, because random jumps of sequential iterators can be _much_ more expensive than for vector iterators, so making them easy would be a significant performance risk. Whereas I don't see reason why `try_emplace` would be much slower for any multimap implementation, than it is on `std::map`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Meh, suppose you're right. Still, I think the general attitude that led to both choices is ultimately the same, despite the difference in practical cost if you go ahead anyway. In fact I've always been rubbed a little wrong when people use _only_ "performance" as an argument for why sequential iterators can't be `+=`'d; there's a strong semantic argument too. It's to stop you writing "bad code", after all, and raw performance isn't everything.

Answer (score 6):

It is not necessary since for multimap case since there is no unique key, `try_emplace` would never fail. The rational for adding `try_emplace` to map was all the error prone code needed to deal with the case that key already exists, see the proposal [n4279](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4279.html) (*emphasis mine*):

> The existing interface of unique-keyed map containers (std::map,
>   std::unordered_map) is slightly underspecified, which **makes certain
>   container mutations more complicated to write and error-prone than
>   necessary**. This paper describes new member function templates to
>   fill this gap.
>
> The justification and rationale for the new interface are given in
>   N3873. The initial reaction to N3873 in Issaquah was that the existing
>   map interfaces should be fixed rather than adding new interfaces. We
>   explored this idea in N4006 in Rapperswil and decided that the
>   original proposal was preferable (with some name changes). This paper
>   only summarises the proposed extension without repeating the original
>   discussion. We only restate the motivating code snippet here for
>   motivation:
>
> ```
> std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Foo>> m;
> m["foo"] = nullptr;
>
> auto ptr = std::make_unique_ptr<Foo>;
> auto res = m.emplace("foo", std::move(ptr));
>
> assert(ptr);    // ??? (may or may not fire)
> ```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but it's kind of against intuition that ptr would still be valid after std::move is called on it.

Comment: @LeiYu `std::move` does not modify the object by itself it just makes it possible, you need to change your intuition. For example `auto p1 = std::unique_ptr<int>(); auto &&p2 = std::move( p1 );` - p1 is not affected

Comment: @LeiYu Only because `std::move` is the wrong name for what it does! (Important people have since admitted this.) You have indeed found a perfect example of why that is.

Comment: @LeiYu You need to see the std::move as a cast not as a real move